# invoking interface method in abstract class method

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, invoke

The code is running but I would like to understand the topic better and I am not sure how to name the problem. How is it possible that in abstract class method I can invoke an interface method if the interface method is empty? Could anyone please tell me how this kind of operation is called in Java? In my uni classes I attend, the slide names the problem as  "Programming through API" but I cannot find anything when I google it.

I have an interface class which has getBalance method:

```
public interface BankAccount {

int getBalance();
...
}
```

Then I am invoking the interface method in an abstract Class method:

```
public abstract class AbstractBankAccount implements BankAccount {

private final bankAccountNo;
private int accountBalance;  

abstractBankAccount(int bankAccountNo) {
    this.bankAccountNo = bankAccountNo;
}

public void transferBalance(bankAccount account) {

// so here is what I am struggling to understand: account.getBalance() is called, but getBalance() method in interface is empty, how does it work then? 

final int accountBal = account.getBalance();

    if (accountBal < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("not enough money on the account");

    accountBalance += accountBal;

    account.withdraw(accountBal);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my uni classes I attend, the slide names the problem as
>   "Programming through API" but I cannot find anything when I google it.

and

> How is it possible that in abstract class method I can invoke an
>   interface method if the interface method is empty?

In methods of a concrete class, you could encounter exactly the same situation.
Here the interface defines a contract : methods to implement but these are all abstract in the interface.
To program by interface, the code that manipulates the concept put in an interface (here BankAccount) should not directly reference the concrete class of the interface but the interface itself if we want to be able to switch to another implementation class of the interface.

That's why  `public void transferBalance(BankAccount account)`  is defined with a `BankAccount` type as parameter.

Of course at a time a concrete class has to be selected and instantiated but it is the single time where it should be specified.

A client code that perform a transfer could write :

```
// I instantiate concrete classes but I refer interface as declared type.
BankAccount bankAcountDebitor = new ConcreteBankAccount();
BankAccount bankAcountCreditor = new ConcreteBankAccount();

// I invoke a method that takes as argument a type derived from the interface type 
bankAcountDebitor.transferBalance(bankAcountCreditor);
```

In this way, even if a day we switch to another concrete `BankAccount` representation :

```
bankAcountDebitor.transferBalance(bankAcountCreditor);
```

will still compile fine as the method takes as parameter the interface type.

So you could write that :

```
BankAccount bankAcountDebitor = new ConcreteUniversalBankAccount();
BankAccount bankAcountCreditor = new ConcreteUniversalBankAccount();

bankAcountDebitor.transferBalance(bankAcountCreditor);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I understand it well? Does 'account' parameter in my transferBalance() method always refer to a concrete implementation of interface class(eg. ConcreteBankAccount)? Is it this kind of operation called "programming by interface" in Java?

Comment: You are welcome :) 1) yes the passed parameter always refers to a concrete implementation of interface class. It is a compilation constraint as for the parameter the compiler needs both a concrete instance but it has also to derive from the declared interface type. 2) In your actual code `public void transferBalance(BankAccount account)` refers to programming by interface. We expose the `BankAccount` interface as declared type. So we can pass any implementation of `BankAccount` as parameter and the passed object will be handled only as the `BankAccount` interface exposes it.

Answer (score 3):

In an abstract class some methods are left for concrete inheritors to implement.

Although the method is empty (abstract) now, when you create a non-abstract implementation you'll have to give a body to that method. that body is what will be called.

Here is an example:

```
abstract class Parent {
  abstract String someMethod();

  public String getValue() {
    return someMethod();//how could this work?! someMethod() has no body!
  }
}

class Child extends Parent {

  @Override
  String someMethod() { //this won't compile unless I implement someMethod()
    return "data";
  }
}
```

Although someMethod() is abstract in Parent, you can't actually create an instance of Parent (because it is abstract). You have to extend it, which requires you provide an implementation of someMethod().

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that when this is run, the `account` parameter will be an instance of a concrete class that implements bankAccount.getBalance(). This is how Abstraction works

Comment: Thank you, that clears things up for me. Is this sort of action in Java called "programming by interface"?